# opening a file.txt and displaying the content in a input text box node js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, fs

i want to display the content of a text file in a input text box.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Write&ReadFiles</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="writeread.css">
<script src="write.js"></script>
<body>
    <h1>Write & Read Files</h1>
    <div class="read">
        <form name="form">
            <h3>File Name:</h3> <input class="input" name="textview" type="text">
            <h3>Text:</h3> <input class="input" name="textview2" type="text"><br><br>
            <input class="button" type="button" value="ENTER" onclick="doit()">
        </form>
    </div>
        <div class="write">

        </div>
    </body>
</head>
```

Javascript file:

```
var fs = require('fs');

function doit() {
    var text = document.form.textview.value;
    fs.readFile(toString(text), function(err, buf) {
        document.form.textview2.value === buf.toString();
    }); 
}
```

Any help will be appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: So where is the Ajax call to the node.js code?

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry I'm still a newbie at this.